# Rebol Saphirion GUI test-driven-development (TDD)

Tags: tdd, rebol, rebol3

Where can I find Rebol R3-GUI library Saphirion GUI TDD ?

(as featured in http://development.saphirion.com/rebol/r3gui/)

I looked through r3-gui.r3 but I am yet to find any TDD related code.

A more general question :  is any test framework available besides Rebol 2, Rebol 3 own language test suite ?

Comment: Hello @OneArb, welcome to StackOverflow.  This is a "polling" type question--in that it doesn't have a clearly defined answer to solve a problem.  You can [read some about that issue here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).   This is a good topic to bring up in forums or chat, although unfortunately it takes 20 points to get to chat here.  [They're relatively easy to get!](https://trello.com/c/itorjj3b), so you might try some more specific questions (or answers).

Comment: Thanks for your comment,

Hope my edit squares question to guidelines.

Answer (score 3):

I have not heard of any GUI testing framework other than the Saphirion one (which I have not actually seen).

There are are three testing frameworks of which I am aware:

1. RUnit - a Rebol version of JUnit - http://www.rebol.org/view-script.r?script=run.r
2. Simple-Test - A slightly more flexible approach - http://www.rebol.org/view-script.r?script=simple-test.r docs at http://peterwawood.com/simple-test/docs.html
3. Quick-Unit-Test.r - Very minimalist - https://github.com/red/red/tree/master/quick-test

Comment: Saphirion have another GUI testing framework which they use with rebgui for rebol2. Just for internal use as I understand it.